# How to request with random row linq

Tags: linq

I am slow today

There is a request 
"Take random child and put it into another garden."

I changed the code, but error in the last line of code "Does not contain a definition…and no extension method":

```
var query = db.Child.Where(x => x.Garden != null); 
int count = query.Count(); 
int index = new Random().Next(count); 
var ch = db.Child.OrderBy(x => query.Skip(index).FirstOrDefault()); 
ch.Garden_Id = "1";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell what you're doing wrong, because you didn't say why the results you're getting does not satisfy you.

But I can see two possible mistakes.

- You're counting items with `x.Garden != null` condition, but taking from all children.
- `Take` returns `IEnumerable<T>` even when you specify it to return only `1` item, you should probably use `First` instead.

I think your `k` should be

```
var k = db.Child.Where(x => x.Garden != null).Skip(rnd.Next(0,q)).First();
```